# Reference for finite Von Neumann algebra

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm looking for a reference where I can read about very basic properties and examples of finite VN-algebras. I will be happy with one that defines the concept in an "easy" language (for a second year MSc student) and gives you also the motives for the definition. Especially why they are called finite.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is in every major operator algebras book: Kadison-Ringrose, Takesaki, Sakai, etc. But I'm not sure that you'll find a very unified approach. The book by Sinclair and Smith is all about finite von Neumann algebras, but it is probably more advanced.